# Querying Spotfire for a folder's childItems takes too long

Tags: spotfire, tibco

Our Index page displays a list of the analysis files located in a folder (each user has a folder in the Spotfire's Library). The problem is performance. It takes ~5 seconds to get 50 library items and because that happens in our landing page, the whole page takes too long to load. I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong when querying the server.

We have a method `GetWorkbooks()` (see below) in our service which is called when the landing page loads. It uses a `WcfClient` which exposes the `LibraryService` so we can query spotfire.

```
public IList<Workbook> GetWorkbooks(string email, bool isBufferFolder = false)
{
    var targetFolderPath = isBufferFolder ? _sharingBufferFolderPath : _userFolderPath;

    var userFolderId = _spotfireUserDataService._libraryService
        .Invoke(x => x.pathToId(new pathToId($"{targetFolderPath}/{email}", SpotfireLibraryItemType.Folder))).@return;

    var workBooks = new List<Workbook>();

    // only retrieve workbooks if there is a user folder
    if (userFolderId != null)
    {
        var libraryItems = _spotfireUserDataService._libraryService.Invoke(x => x.getChildItems(new getChildItems(userFolderId))).@return;
        // check if there are any items in the folder, if not return the above empty list
        if (libraryItems != null)
        {// get all analysis/workbook ('dxp') files for the user
            workBooks = libraryItems
                .Where(i => i.type == SpotfireLibraryItemType.DXP)
                .OrderByDescending(j => j.accessed.Date)
                .Select(x => new Workbook {
                    Name = x.title,
                    Id = x.id,
                    ModifiedDate = x.modified,
                    Metadata = new WorkbookMetadata
                    {
                        SharedBy = x.properties.Where(i => i.key == "SharedBy").FirstOrDefault()?.values[0],
                        SharedDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(x.properties.Where(i => i.key == "SharedDate").FirstOrDefault()?.values[0]))
                    }
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    return workBooks;
}
```

This is a screenshot of the call:

[image]

This is the Spotfire's Library hierarchy:

```
-DNA
----UserFolder
--------user.name@company.com
```

This is my `WcfClient.cs`:

```
public class WcfClient<T> : IDisposable
{
    private T _wrappedChannel;
    private static readonly object _channelLock = new object();
    private readonly ChannelFactory<T> _factory;
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public WcfClient(ChannelFactory<T> factory, ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    protected T WrappedChannel
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_channelLock)
            {
                if (!Equals(_wrappedChannel, default(T)))
                {
                    var state = ((ICommunicationObject)_wrappedChannel).State;
                    if (state == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    {
                        _wrappedChannel = default(T);
                    }
                }
                if (Equals(_wrappedChannel, default(T)))
                {
                    _wrappedChannel = _factory.CreateChannel();
                }
            }
            return _wrappedChannel;
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(Action<T> action)
    {
        try
        {
            action(WrappedChannel);
        }
        catch (FaultException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException)
        {
            _tokenProvider.Invalidate();
            action(WrappedChannel);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            action(WrappedChannel);
        }
    }

    public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> action)
    {
        try
        {
            return action(WrappedChannel);
        }
        catch (FaultException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException)
        {
            _tokenProvider.Invalidate();
            return action(WrappedChannel);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException e)
        {
            return action(WrappedChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone please provide any tips on how I can improve the performance?

Comment: my first thought was the lamda expressions, since I've had some performance hits when combining a bunch of them, but I see you've got a long delay on the hit to the server. are there any examples in the SDK that might shed some light on a different way to browse the library? he asked, without looking. take a look at the SpotfireDeveloper.ApiExamples project's LibraryExamples.cs. sorry that I don't have a good solution off the bat; I'm a bit behind on my own extension project :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Niko! I will definitely have a look as I am not sure of the current implementation is the most performant, I am curious to see what method of querying the Spotfire server is used in the samples :)